# Array keys get lost as they are considered numeric

Tags: php, arrays, key, array-key

Let's say there exists an array:

```
$array = array(
    '1001' => 'a',
    '1002' => 'b',
    '1003' => 'c',
);
```

Now let's say someone wants reverse that array:

```
$array = array_reverse($array);
```

The problem is, that `array_reverse` seems to cast all numeric values to integers and then resets the indexes:

```
0 => 'c'  - should be '1003' => 'c'
1 => 'b'  - should be '1002' => 'b'
2 => 'a'  - should be '1001' => 'a'
```

What someone may have also tried was this - but without any luck (as expected):

```
$array[(string) $index] = 'a';
```

You can even experience this yourself [here on codepad](http://codepad.org/tDhXI4cF).

How can this be solved? Do I have to write my own mapping function, which can handle this or is there any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you just need to use the following code:

```
array_reverse($array, true)
```

As per php documentation, to preserve keys you must set 2nd parameter to `true`